# Changing the background color of PNG Image while keeping search button in white color instead of grey color

Tags: icon, png, css

I have the search button image on my site which has black background and grey search button and this is PNG image with the following code in stylesheet.css

[image: Search Button in PNG Image]

```
.topsearch .btn-search {
    width:29px;
    height:29px;
    background:url(images/btn_search.png) no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2}
```

I want to change the black background color to orange color while displaying the search button in it in white color with the help of coding in CSS in stylesheet.css without physically changing the image.

Please guide me how can do this as I do not know the coding need help.

Comment: What does this have to do with graphic design?

Comment: It's graphics and it's design. I got into coding to bring my graphic design to life. I started off with ActionScript, then went on to using CSS3 to make cool graphics and graphic effects. As an example, you can use code to draw SVG's on webpages and style it with more code, usally CSS. For me, code is just as much a part of graphic design as using Photoshop (which you can also use code in to manpiulat SVG's and other graphics). A browser is just a new type of pallet.

Comment: However @Nemish, you would usually get a quicker and more detailed answer if you posted in Stack Overflow  https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

### Transparent PNG's and SVG's With CSS

To do this with CSS you need to do either of two things.

1. Make your PNG(s) with colour and transparency. You can then use CSS to manipulate the colours. The main icon would be manipulated using something like the CSS [hue-rotate filter](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_filter&preval=hue-rotate(90deg))

The below code will colour your PNG and background, then changes the colours on `mouse:hover`.

The `filter:hue-rotate(90deg);` number you use to achieve the colour you require, depends on the colour of your image.

---

```
   .topsearch .btn-search {
      position:relative;
      width:29px;
      height:29px;
      background:url(images/btn_search.png) no-repeat;
      filter:hue-rotate(90deg);
      background-color:#FFA500; /*#FFA500 = orange in hex*/
      z-index:2}
    }
   .topsearch .btn-search:hover {
      filter:hue-rotate(50deg);
      background-color:#000; /*#000 = blackin hex*/
}
```

---

2. Use an SVG with HTML and CSS and to create and [manipulate](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/manipulating-svg-icons-with-simple-css--webdesign-15694) your icon.

---

```
svg {
  fill:#FFA500;
  /*stroke:#fff; uncomment if required*/
  stroke-width:.5;
  background-color:#555 /*#555 = grey*/;
}
```

[image]